# change image of rightCalloutAccessoryView's button of annotation view in Map view

Tags: ios, swift

how to change image of rightCalloutAccessoryView's button of annotation view in Map view? I have used following method to set button in annotation view.

```
annotationView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
```

`(annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView as! UIButton).setImage(UIImage(named: "abc"), for: .normal)`

I have also tried with custom button, it won't change

Comment: It can be interesting for you. Maybe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407978/how-to-add-two-or-more-buttons-to-annotationview-mkannotationview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this way create `Button`, set `image` and set `Button` as `rightCalloutAccessoryView`.

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "abc"), for: .normal)
annotationView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4**

Create your button, set the image and assign in rightCalloutView.

```
let annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
let rightButton = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
rightButton.setImage( UIImage(named: "map1"), for: .normal)
annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton
```

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 3.0** 
Try this
you can set server url image in callout.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
        marker.tracksInfoWindowChanges = true
        let CustomWindowDisplay:CustomWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("View", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! CustomWindow
        let arrImages:NSArray = (dictDataOfPropertyData.value(forKey: "property_images") as? NSArray)!
        if arrImages.count != 0{
            let strImage:String = (arrImages1.object(at: 0) as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "property_photo") as! String

            let urlofImg:NSURL = NSURL.init(string: strImage)!
            CustomWindowDisplay.imgPropertyPhoto.sd_setImage(with: urlofImg as URL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder_main_list.png"), options: .highPriority)
        }
    }
```