# How to chage CustomPointAnnotation title View?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I want to change default title view of CustomPointAnnotation to something else, at this time it looks like this

[image]

and I want it to look like this

[image]

is it possible and how it can be done.

Comment: you need to create custom annotation view.

Comment: Yes this is a custom annotation but how to change the title view UI

Comment: Use MKAnnotationView to add custom annotation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241340/how-to-add-custom-view-in-maps-annotations-callouts/19404994#19404994

Comment: you can change on viewForAnnotation delegate method of mapview .

Comment: you can find useful code here: my answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407978/how-to-add-two-or-more-buttons-to-annotationview-mkannotationview